# TypeError: missing dsn and no parameters cuando cambio mi base de datos

Tags: python, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando cambiar [una simple aplicación de chat](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) a una más compleja siguiendo [este tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database). Ahora estoy descifrando cómo cambiar mi base de datos. La maestra eligió Flask-SQLAlchemy y SQLite pero ya comencé con PostgreSQL. Así que trato de modificar mi aplicación poco a poco para poder usar es, lo que parece ser más serio.

Sin embargo, probé el simple comando `> from app.models import User` y obtuve un`TypeError: missing dsn and no parameters`.

```
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app.models import User
/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    raise TypeError('missing dsn and no parameters')
TypeError: missing dsn and no parameters
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    raise TypeError('missing dsn and no parameters')
TypeError: missing dsn and no parameters
```

¿Debería comentar mi antigua base de datos?

```
# Online Database
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
```

Comment: No entiendo, ¿quiere usar MySQL? `psycopg2` es una librería para PostgreSQL.

Comment: @César Disculpe, utilisaba PostgreSQL y quiero utilisar la misma usada en [este tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)